# Using SQL JSON_MODIFY to add/update a dictionary value

Tags: json, sql-server, dictionary

Is it possible to use JSON_MODIFY to update a dictionary value of <int,string>?
If my JSON is this:

```
{
  "items": {
     "1": "xxx",
     "2": "xxx",
     "3": "xxx"
  }
}
```

I'm unable to add/update using the following:

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 1
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(50) = 'zzz'
UPDATE MyTable SET MyJsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(MyJsonColumn, CONCAT('$.items.', @Id), @Value)
```

I get the error: `JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '1' is found at position 10.` obviously because property names can't be numeric. I can workaround the error using a <string,string> dictionary as follows:

```
{
  "items": {
     "i1": "xxx",
     "i2": "xxx",
     "i3": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Then the following works fine:

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 1
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(50) = 'zzz'
UPDATE MyTable SET MyJsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(MyJsonColumn, CONCAT('$.items.i', @Id), @Value)
```

However, now I'm tasked with extra work after deserializing the JSON to get the numeric ID I actually want. It's just a minor inconvenience, but I was hoping for a possible solution to keep my <int,string> dictionary. Any ideas?

I suppose I could use a dictionary like this <string,object> and simply ignore the keys when deserialized:

```
{
  "items": {
     "i1": { "id": 1, "name": "xxx" },
     "i2": { "id": 1, "name": "xxx" },
     "i3": { "id": 1, "name": "xxx" }
  }
}
```

And then use

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyJsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(MyJsonColumn, CONCAT('$.items.i', @Id), JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('{"id":', @Id, ',"name":"', @Value, '"}')))
```

I'm also not opposed to using an array as such:

```
{
  "items": [
     { "id": 1, "name": "xxx" },
     { "id": 2, "name": "xxx" },
     { "id": 3, "name": "xxx" }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know a way to update/add when in this format, and the add/update has to be done in a single UPDATE statement.

I'm hoping for some magic formula to continue using my <int,string> dictionary.

Comment: You *can* access properties which are made up of just numbers, you just need to escape it with quotes `""`, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=491e3d6c12b565663a8c92c1570b48ae. What you are trying to do is pretty difficult: you either need to run `JSON_MODIFY` multiple times, or you need to rebuild the JSON with `FOR JSON`. But if you don't have a fixed list of properties then you would need to manually build it using `STRING_AGG`. Are there always exactly 3 properties?

Comment: @Charlieface Man, that was so simple! Navigating using the double quotes is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Charlieface, the solution is quite simple. You can navigate to numeric dictionary keys via double quotes:

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 1
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(50) = 'zzz'

UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyJsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(ISNULL(MyJsonColumn, '{"items":{}}'), CONCAT('$.items."', @Id, '"'), @Value)
```

Comment: Note that using a non-constant (calculated) path in `JSON_MODIFY` only works in version 2017+. This is another reason you shouldn't put data into keys, they are like table columns and *define* the data, they shouldn't themselves be data.